# How to solve <BEA-101366>

Tags: java, weblogic, wicket, weblogic12c

In My Java application I have clicked on Wicket dropdown value and application processing our logic then we got below error in logs and nothing in my application.

```
<BEA-101366> <The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.>
```

I have increased the value of CompleteMessageTimeout to 90 in WebLogic and its working but i want to know why this error is coming in the application and can we solve this issue without increase the value in WebLogic because i will prefer any change in the java code.

I am using below technology in my application:

1. Java 1.5
2. Wicket 1.3
3. WebLogic 12c
4. Spring
5. Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can take a thread dump after the action (click) and see where your application is stuck. From there you can decide what you need to do.

A wild guess but I would bet on some database operation taking too long.

Comment: so if i tune db operation then we don't need to increase CompleteMessageTimeout value and how we will take thread dump.

Comment: so if i tune db operation then we don't need to increase CompleteMessageTimeout value and how we will take thread dump.

Comment: You can take a thread dump with `kill -3 PROCESS_ID` (Unix, Linux) or attach to the Java process with `jconsole` and click the button in it. You better google for more details.